# How do I emulate Sed's y command?

Tags: ex-mode

For the very first time I find myself in need for the `y` command Sed has.

For those who don't know what `y` does, here's an example:

```
$ echo x1 x2 x3 | sed 'y/123/234/'
x2 x3 x4
```

Apparently Vim has no way of doing this. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure it does. In unix there's often a command equivalent to `sed y/X/x/` called `tr`. So...

```
echo "A1B2C3" | sed 'y/ABC/abc/'  # prints "a1b2c3"
```

...is equivalent to...

```
echo "A1B2C3" | tr 'ABC' 'abc'  # also print "a1b2c3"
```

It happens that Vim has a function that is "exactly like the unix 'tr' command": [`:h tr()`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#tr())

So...

```
:echo tr("A1B2C3", "ABC", "abc")
```

That will print, of course, "a1b2c3".

Comment: I think you can be promoted to A Layer, if B is a ranking :P

Comment: LOL. First time I've heard that one. Thanks for the compliment. ;)

Answer (score 6):

BLayer’s answer nicely covers the vimscript equivalent for programming.

For completeness, you can also perform these operations on a buffer:

- on a *nix, `:[range]!sed …` or `:[range]!tr …` (this is often easier to type with the normal-mode `!` operator, which prefills the `:[range]!`)
- entirely portably, `:[range]substitute/[charset1]\+/\=tr(submatch(0), charset1, charset2)/`

There’s a version of the last with a dictionary, but it’s slightly less readable to my eyes. Unfortunately both require you to repeat the starting set of characters, unless you use the pattern `.\+` (which may be slower, as vim will consider every character of every line, rather than batching groups to be translated; benchmark if it matters to you).

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe a line, or any selection of lines through a UNIX command.

So in your example, position your cursor on the line you wish to modify, and then type ":" to get into edit/command mode and add a ".|" meaning pipe the current line though a command, and then type your command.

:.| sed 'y/123/234/'

This is an amazing capability, you can designate a range of line, or pattern match lines as well of course.

Comment: You might want to [edit] with a particular eye towards [formatting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I do believe you meant type `.!` instead of `.|`. Also note that this information is covered in my answer.